# How to store .format() print output to a var for reuse

Tags: python, dictionary, format

I have a list of dictionaries which i want to display using Tkinter.
So far i only managed to print the desired result.

Example code:

```
for x in list:
    for key, value in x.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
>>>key: value
   key: value
   key: value
```

The way it's printed is the exact way i want to display it on the application. How do i store this output as text?

Comment: Instead of `print()` just set the string equal to a variable

Comment: Do you want to store the output in a .txt file?

Comment: For performance reasons, I encourage you to use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) if you have python > 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
out = ""
for x in list:
    for key, value in x.items():
        out += "{}: {}\n".format(key, value))
print(out)
```